# Find array values in Object

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that takes an object and an array. I loop through the array and use the value as a key to look in the object.

I would like the loop to stop as soon as 1 value has been found and return that value. Somehow i keep getting undefined when running this function.

```js
const searchInObject = function(obj, keys) {
  //if array => loop and return the first value that is found.
  //if not array and type is string find in object
  // if no array or undefined return default value
  if (Array.isArray(keys)) {
    keys.map(key => {
      if (obj[key]) return obj[key];
    })
  }
};


const obj = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2'
};
console.log(searchInObject(obj, ['a', 'b']));
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function. Also, what is the expected output? An array of values or a subset of the object? *"return the first value that is found"* is confusing

Comment: `return keys.map...`??

Comment: I made a snippet.  I changed from util. because the function is not part of any util object

Comment: Returns both values still, i wish to return the first that is found. @JaydipJadhav

Comment: @adiga Basically i want to return one value only. That value is the first key in the loop that can be also found in the object. In this case its ' a '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop through the keys and check if the key exists in `obj`. If it does, return the value

```js
const searchInObject = function(obj, keys) {
  if (!Array.isArray(keys))
    return;

  for (const key of keys) {
    if (key in obj)
      return obj[key]
  }
};

const obj = { a: '1', b: '2' };

console.log(searchInObject(obj, ['a', 'b']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const searchInObject = function(obj, keys) {
  if (Array.isArray(keys)) { //if array => loop and return the first value that is found.
    for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
      if (obj[keys[i]]) return obj[keys[i]];
    }
  } else if (typeof keys === 'string') { //if not array and type is string find in object
    return obj[keys];
  } else { // if no array or undefined return default value
    return "default value"; // change this to the default value you want
  }
};


const obj = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2'
};
console.log(searchInObject(obj, ['a', 'b']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function instead. This returns the first found value or `undefined` if nothing is found.

```js
const searchInObject = (obj, keys) => {
    if (Array.isArray(keys))
        return keys.find(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
    else return undefined;
}

console.log(searchInObject({a: '1', b: '2'}, ['a','b']))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use `filter` instead of `map`.

Below is the code:

```
const searchInObject = function(obj, keys) { 
    if(keys instanceof Array) { 
        keys = keys.filter(key => { 
            // This will return undefined if key is not present in object
            return obj[key];
        });
        // The filtered keys array will contain only existing keys
        // If length of keys is non zero then just return the value with first key 
        // Else return -1 or any other value
        return keys.length > 0 ? obj[keys[0]] : -1;
    }
    // If keys is not an array, return -1 (or anything else if you want to)
    return -1;
};
```

The above code will still loop through the entire `keys` array even if it finds the first `key` in `obj`. To optimize it, instead of using `map` or `filter`, you can just iterate over `keys` and return the first existing value.

Here's the code:

```
const searchInObject = function(obj, keys) { 
    if(keys instanceof Array) { 
        for(let key of keys) {
            if(obj[key])
                return obj[key];
        }
    }
    // If keys is not an array, return -1 (or anything else if you want to)
    return -1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Practically it not possible using the <kbd>[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)</kbd> function to break its iteration. better way you try to use for loop or try something like below.

```
return keys.map(key => {
      if (obj[key]) return obj[key];
    })[0]
```

Comment: If keys is `["c", "a"]`, this will return undefined. This is same as `return obj[keys[0]]`